# Went really far, went to/through to the final

Tags: word-usage

If a person makes it through to the finals,  is it okay to say:

> She went to the finals.

Or

> She went through to the finals.

And what about:

> She went really far.  (in the competition)

The last sentence isn't really about finals but about the overall journey (most probably used when the person lost..)

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic way to say it is

> She **made it** to the finals.

The Lexico (Oxford) dictionary has this as meaning **6** of the verb [**make**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/make).

> **6** Manage to arrive at (a place) within a specified time or catch (a train or other form of transport)
>   *they didn't always make it on time*
>
> **6.1** (make it) Become successful.
>   *he waited confidently for his band to make it*
>
> **6.2** (make it) Succeed in reaching safety or in surviving.
>   *the pilot didn't make it—his neck's broken*
>
> **6.3** Achieve a place in.
>   *Australia should make the final*
>
> **6.4** Achieve the rank of.
>   *he wasn't going to make captain*

---

For the second question, your phrase doesn't quite seem right, I don't know why.

When the person lost, you could say

> She did extremely well.

I can't think of references to support that, just my feeling about what is idiomatic.

Comment: And what about: She went really far. (Not really finals...)

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: And what about : "She made it really far in the competition. "

Comment: To "make it" does not have degrees: you either make it, or you don't. So the same answer: she did very/extremely well in the competition. Or you could say "She made it to the quarter final".